# How to redefine \cite for bib-entries with certain option?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-philosophy, declarecitecommand

For some titles with a certain `shorthand` I need to redefine the output-format of citations: The `postnote` must not be printed *after* the citation but *within* (`\printfield{postnote}`), and it must not be printed twice (within *and* after). Now, I can declare new cite commands and use them for these entries.

What I would rather like: Tell `biblatex` to use the new citation format for entries with `options = {XEN}` or `{XEN=true}`, even with ordinary `\cite`.

```
% uses-*- MODE: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\documentclass[paper=A7, DIV=16,landscape,fontsize=8pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,sortlocale=de,language=auto,%
            sorting=nyvt,backend=biber,hyperref=true,shorthandintro=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{shortbib.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
% from philosophy-classic.cbx
\DeclareCiteCommand{\XENcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \switchATAY{citetitle:AT}{citeyear}}%
  {}
  {} % removed \usebibmacro{postnote}
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\XENparencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \switchATAY{citetitle:AT}{citeyear}}
  {}
  {} % removed \usebibmacro{postnote}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\XENfootcitet}[\mkbibfootnote] % \XENfootcitet
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}%
  {} % removed \usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\verb|\cite|: \cite[5]{Cardauns:VarroRD}, \cite[Xenophanes
17]{Gentili:PE1} and \cite[87]{Xenophanes:TP}

\smallskip
should be like \verb|\XENcite| for \verb|bib|-entries with
\verb|options = {XEN}|: \XENcite[5]{Cardauns:VarroRD},
\XENcite[Xenophanes 17]{Gentili:PE1} and \XENcite[87]{Xenophanes:TP}

\nocite{*}
\printshorthands

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{shortbib.bib}
@MVBook{Cardauns:VarroRD,
  author =   {Burkhart Cardauns},
  options =      {XEN},
  title =    {Varro \mkbibemph{Antiquitates}},
  date =     1976,
  langid =   {german},
  publisher =    {Steiner},
  location =     {Wiesbaden},
  pagination =   {none},
  shorthand =    {\printfield{postnote}\addnbspace\mkbibemph{RD}},
  keywords =     {shorthand}
}

@Book{Gentili:PE1,
  author =   {Bruno Gentili},
  options =      {XEN},
  title =    {Callinus, Tyrtaeus, Xenophanes},
  langid =   {latin},
  date =     1988,
  publisher =    {Teubner},
  location =     {Leipzig},
  pagination =   {none},
  shorthand =    {\printfield{postnote}\addnbspace\mkbibemph{PE}\addnbspace\RN{1}},
  keywords =     {shorthand}
}

@Book{Xenophanes:TP,
  author =   {Benedikt Strobel},
  options =      {XEN},
  title =    {Xenophanes von Kolophon},
  langid =   {english},
  date =     2018,
  publisher =    {Gruyter},
  location =     {Berlin},
  pagination =   {none},
  shorthand =    {XEN\addnbspace\printfield{postnote}\addnbspace\mkbibemph{TP}\addnbthinspace3},
  keywords =     {shorthand}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\end{document}
```

[image: new cite format]

Comment: May I ask for the reason you don't like to use your own `XENcite` commands if they are working?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [`archaeologie`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/archaeologie) biblatex style. Entries with the option `frgancient` seem to fit your needs (documentation p. 32 f.). For example the Teubner edition by Lindsay of *Festus* is cited `\cite[3]{Fest}` and prints **Fest. 3 L.**.